# The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml in eclipse webservice

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

Im running a score and scoreservices class in eclipse dynamic project 
i created a webservice and ran it but it gives me errors saying `The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml`. Dont know what to do with this output

score class

```
package startAgain;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Score {
public int wins, losses, ties;
}
```

ScoreServies class

```
package startAgain;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.jws.*;
@Stateless
@WebService
public class ScoreService {
private static Score score = new Score();
public Score updateScore (int wins, int losses, int ties) {
    score.wins = wins;
    score.losses = losses;
    score.ties = ties;
    return score;
}
@WebMethod(operationName="resetScore")
public void reset() {
score.wins = score.losses = score.ties = 0;
}
        public Score getScore() { return score; }
        public int increaseWins() { return score.wins++; }
        public int increaseTies() { return ++score.ties; }
        public int increaseLosses() { return ++score.losses; }
        public int getWins() { return score.wins; }
        public int getTies() { return score.ties; }
        public int getLosses() { return score.losses; }

}
```

Any help on this on clearing this package javax.xml.namespace error
Thanks

Comment: If your project has a module-info.java file that you did not intentionally create, delete it.

Comment: The system library contains the module `java.xml` with the package `javax.xml.namespace`, but the package `javax.xml.namespace` is also somewhere contained on the classpath (`<unnamed>`): in a dependency on the classpath or in your code not having a `module-info.java`. This is not allowed in Java 9 and higher.

Comment: @nitind there is no mudule-info.java file created

Comment: @howlger where would i add module-info.java then to work around this issue

Comment: @dave There is no workaround for this. Use Java 8, get rid of the dependency (or the package in your code) or exclude the `java.xml` system module (but I guess, both are need). In most cases the solution is to update the dependencies (assuming the package `javax.xml.namespace` is not used in your code).

Comment: @dave Did you get a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: It sounds like what has been described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/1016514

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with Eclipse few days ago.

So I tried to find the library that proposed the same package (`javax.xml.namespace`) already available in the `javax.xml` Java built-in module, provoking package duplication.

In my case it was a library under the name `stax-api`.
I just removed it from the build, like this:

```
dependencies {
...
  configurations {
       compile.exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
  }
...
}
```