# "The package ***** is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml" error only when deploying feature but not in code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-11

I'm trying to export a deployable feature for my eclipse program, every time I try to export it with jdk17 which we're just upgrading to I get the "The package *********** is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml" in a certain plugin project but does not cause any error in the code.
I need the compliance level to stay on jdk17, I'm also not sure if plugin projects are generated modularized because according to eclipse trying to create the module-info.java "may not be synchronized with the manifest file", and creating a new plugin project doesn't generate said file.
Packages providing the error are:

- javax.xml.parsers
- org.w3c.dom
- org.xml.sax

I'm using a custom target platform that originally had a version of javax.xml which I now have removed.
Having both types in my project gives the same error but, in the code, and when exporting feature. Having only the jdk17 version still produces the error when exporting.

So far, I have tried:

- Remove the javax.xml from the target platform
- Remove the dependency from MANIFEST.MF of the project that has the issue
- Checked the types in the project to ensure that it does not exist in more than one module, anything using javax.xml comes from the jdk now
- Create a new workspace with the project and restarting my PC

I also followed the steps in these questions among others with no luck.
[Eclipse is confused by imports ("accessible from more than one module")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)
[Package accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902512/package-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed)

Comment: A system library of Java 9 and higher always consists of modules which cannot be changed. An Eclipse plugin must not contain a `module-info.java` since [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) does not allow to start and stop modules at runtime in contrast to OSGi bundles. It seems removing the `javax.xml` plugin/bundle was not enough and you still have a plugin/bundle that contains the `javax.xml` package. For details read https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250

Comment: I have the same issue because of a 3rd party jar I'm required to use HOWEVER opening the same project in IntelliJ does not exhibit this behavior. I guess I'm confused why this isn't an Eclipse bug (or feature removal request).

Comment: @stackbacker Eclipse does it right. It's a confirmed(!) bug of `javac` not showing this as an error. IntelliJ does not have its own compiler and uses `javac` by default.

Comment: @howlger So the issue is that Eclipse is correctly reporting the error while IntelliJ and VSCode (& maybe Netbeans) do not? FWIW the overwhelming response from devs on my project upon hearing that issue only exists (or is reported by) Eclipse was "Just use IntelliJ or VSCode". Maybe it's just me, but if "use a competing product"  is the quick fix for a problem it's something I'd want to address with my product.

Comment: @stackbacker According to the Java language specification it's an error. Eclipse and [VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61278108/6505250) which is based on Eclipse show this error by default. As far as I know, all of today's Java VMs run the code, regardless of the fact that it is invalid Java. You can hide the error message in Eclipse. You can also switch to a text editor or IDE that is blind for this kind of error. Beside the fact that it is an error, it is also a code smell that should be better fixed (very likely caused by a dependency that is many years behind).